# Script Error: ReCaptcha blocked on Microsoft Office products. MS Word, MS PowerPoint

Tags: javascript, ms-word, sharepoint-2013, recaptcha

I am using reCAPTCHA v2 on my SharePoint FBA login page. The captcha works great when I hit my login screen on all browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox).

I complete the CAPTCHA challenge and get authenticated without any problem. Once I am in the site, if I click on any of the Word, PowerPoint documents, Office 2016 client tries to open these documents with the corresponding Office client. At this point, the office client shows me the login screen and asks me to validate. I also get a javascript error "An error has occurred in the script on this page.". The URL being reported is "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js". Screen shot attached! [Captcha Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyzg5.png)

When I hit "Yes"/"No" to continue running scripts, I no longer see the CAPTCHA on my login window. Anyone else encountered this behavior?

Is it a default behavior of MS Office products to block .js files? Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: That is not blocking, it is saying the script is erroring out. The software is probably using an old version of IE as the embedded browser component and probably doesn't support some calls the script is making.

Comment: Thank you Patrick for the quick response. I am thinking what option do I have as a developer. From your comment I understand that Microsoft has to update their Office line of Products in-order to fully support the Google Captcha. I don't know if and when that would happen. Is there anyway that I can get this to work without MS taking action? A registry entry or any other techniques that you could think of? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Or Google updating their script in a way that Office's embedded browser components can understand those calls ;)